# How do I add a number from a column filtered based on the condition of two different column of the pandas dataframe to itself?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, grouping

Required output:

[image: Reuired Output]

I have a table like this where `Country`, `Category` and `Values` are present in the data, I need to create a column like `Total Values` where I need to filter the numbers from `Values` Column based on `Country` level and the `Category` as `Present` then add the numbers to the `Values` column itself to create `Total Values` where the present category values must be added to the respective countries.

As shown in the example, Here `Country` `US` and `CHINA` has categories other than **Present** where I need to add the value of present to other categories to get the **total values ** and the leave the value of present as it is in the total values column.

I'm pretty new to python, I've tried using a for loop to sum the values but I can only add the values from the last row. sharing the code below:

```python
import pandas as pd

data = {'Country': ['US','US','US','US','IND','JP',
                     'CHINA','CHINA'],
        'Category': ['Present','Not Required','Not Present','Not Aware','Present','Present','Present','Not Present'],
       'Values':[2000,2500,3000,2550,1000,500,6000,7000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i in range(0,len(df['Values'])):
    for j in range(0,len(df['Category'])):
        for k in range(0,len(df['Country'])):
            if (i==j==k):
                df['Total Values']= df['Values]+ df['Values][j]
```

And the above code snippet gives me a different output. This adds the number to every row taking the last values in the row.
[Country    Category    Values  Total Values
0   US  Present 2000    9000
1   US  Not Required    2500    9500
2   US  Not Present 3000    10000
3   US  Not Aware   2550    9550
4   IND Present 1000    8000
5   JP  Present 500 7500
6   CHINA   Present 6000    13000
7   CHINA   Not Present 7000    14000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3LvB.png)
I need the output as shown in first image.

Comment: hi Manish! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make your example reproducible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Mark Hi Mark, the above code gives me the output as                                                               Country  Category  Values  Total Values
US  Present  2000  9000
US  Not Required  2500  9500
US  Not Present  3000  10000
US  Not Aware  2550  9550
IND  Present  1000  8000
JP  Present  500  7500
CHINA  Present  6000  13000
CHINA  Not Present  7000  14000

Basically adds the last value of the row and this isn right

Comment: don't post your code into the comments, put the code to reproduce the input dataframe into your question

Comment: @Mark Kindly check now if that helps.

Comment: What if you have several "Present" within one country?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mapping dict:

```
# Extract only values where Category is Present
m = df['Category'] == 'Present'
present = df[m].set_index('Country')['Values']

# Compute the sum for other categories
other = df['Values'] + df['Country'].map(present)
df['Total Values'] = df['Values'].where(m, other=other)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Country      Category  Values  Total Values
0      US       Present    2000          2000
1      US  Not Required    2500          4500
2      US   Not Present    3000          5000
3      US     Not Aware    2550          4550
4     IND       Present    1000          1000
5      JP       Present     500           500
6   CHINA       Present    6000          6000
7   CHINA   Not Present    7000         13000
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend @Corralien's approach, if you have more than one Present per country, you would need to aggregate, for example using a `groupby.transform`:

```
m = df['Category'].ne('Present')

df['Total Values'] = (df['Values'].mask(m)
 .groupby(df['Country'])
 .transform('sum')
 .add(df.loc[m, 'Values'], fill_value=0)
 .where(m, df['Values'])
 )
```

*Depending on whether you want the Total Values for "Present" rows to be the Present of the row or the sum of the Presents of the country, keep or remove the last line of code.*

Output:

```
  Country      Category  Values  Total Values
0      US       Present    2000        2000.0
1      US  Not Required    2500        4500.0
2      US   Not Present    3000        5000.0
3      US     Not Aware    2550        4550.0
4     IND       Present    1000        1000.0
5      JP       Present     500         500.0
6   CHINA       Present    6000        6000.0
7   CHINA   Not Present    7000       13000.0
```